# How to add container multiple time in extjs item of penal

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a container which I am adding in my item of panel.
`me.add(Contain);`

I wanted to add this container multiple time on some condition.  I am using for loop and at end I am writing. `panel.doLayout();` It is appearing only one container is adding. Am I missing something. 
How to old multiple container in item of extjs panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Before add container multiple times in to your panel. Check that container 
you are adding does not have id or itemId as a config property.

So if you want to add that container multiple time you can use that container
with different itemId.
Otherwise it will add only one container and other added container will not
displayed on GUI.
```

Comment: Excellent Answer. It works for me. Thanks a ton @Balram

Comment: Also In one quick note, Container is adding in `panel` now. but `scroll` is not working if item is more.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add the same instance multiple time, think how the rendering system would work as in html the nodes only have 1 parent.

You have to add multiple instance of the container, you could however pass them the same view (if you want to show the same data)

So when you add, you have to create a new version of your container but you could share stores, viewmodel, and other data if you like to

Comment: I am trying to do with `afterrender` by pushing this into an array and appearing on screen but after loading screen getting stuck.

Comment: @user6474292 Are you still using extjs3 as your tag indicates, or already a new version?

Comment: I am using `extjs3`

Comment: I am going to have to guess (I only worked with the later versions), but you should rather add the items during this event (don't forget to remove them afterwards as well) http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Panel-event-beforeadd

Comment: Thanks !! I am trying. Hope this help me.